# Validate file before copying batch file

Tags: batch-file

I was able to copy my entire folder using this script.  Please see details below

```
for %%D in (
   "\\Computer1\Sample\"
   "\\Computer2\Sample\"
   "\\Computer3\Sample\"
   "\\Computer4\Sample\"
) do Xcopy /E /Y "c:\MyProject\Sample*.*" "%%D"
```

Now, i want to validate the file before copying.. Is there a way to accomplish this task..? Using the if condition for batch file.. Sorry, 'm a newbie in batch file creation..

Hope to hear from you soon..

Thanks,

Link

Comment: What do you mean by "validation"?

Comment: example under "c:\Myproject\Sample\*.* i have several files.. Now, i want to copy the entire content of sample except for one file config.file.. is there away to accomplish this..? I want to try if condition, if possible..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may include this line:

```
attrib +h +s "c:\MyProject\SampleExceptThisOne.ext"
```

before your copy, and this line:

```
attrib -h -s "c:\MyProject\SampleExceptThisOne.ext"
```

after the copy. This way, the file with +H +S attribute is not copied by XCOPY commands (as long as you don't include /H option in XCOPY).